# How do I change the power level between two nodes?

Tags: unetstack

How do I decrease the losses by increasing power level?

Here is the code I am using:
https://github.com/maibewakoofhu/Unet

I am changing the power level using:

```
 phy[1].powerLevel = -20.dB;
```

At noise level 68dB, power level = -20dB all *DatagramReq* are sent successfully.

At noise level 70dB, power level = -20dB the *DatagramReq* fails.

Now, increasing the power level to as high as 125dB, still the *DatagramReq* fails.

Comment: What channel model are you using?

Comment: Basic Acoustic Channel

Comment: Then you should see a difference with change in power, unless you're at very high SNR or very low SNR regime. Perhaps you can update your question with more details of your simulation setup and how you concluded that there was no difference.

Comment: I have updated the question with channel details.

Comment: Simulation details posted are not sufficient to reproduce your setup. Need to know other details like node placement, etc. Best to post your simulation setup script, if you can.

Comment: Updated the question with the code.

Comment: what is the difference between all 3 indexed power level and signal power level @MandarChitre

Comment: The indexed power levels are used for the indexed channel. For example `phy[CONTROL].powerLevel` defines the power level for the `CONTROL` channel (e.g. `TxFrameReq(type: CONTROL)`), and `phy[DATA].powerLevel` for `DATA` channel. Other indices may be use defined. The `phy.signalPowerLevel` defines the power level used for arbitrary signal transmission (e.g. `TxBasebandSignalReq`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simpler version of your simulation to test the SNR and packet-loss relationship:

```
import org.arl.fjage.RealTimePlatform
import org.arl.unet.sim.channels.BasicAcousticChannel

platform = RealTimePlatform

channel = [
  model:                BasicAcousticChannel,
  carrierFrequency:     25.kHz,
  bandwidth:            4096.Hz,
  spreading:            2,
  temperature:          25.C,
  salinity:             35.ppt,
  noiseLevel:           73.dB,
  waterDepth:           1120.m
]

simulate {
    node 'C', address: 31, location: [180.m, 0, -1000.m], web: 8101
    node 'A', address: 21, location: [0.m, 0.m, 0.m], web: 8102
}
```

The `web:` entries allows us to interact with each of the nodes to explore what is happening. I connect to each of the nodes (http://localhost:8101/shell.html and http://localhost:8102/shell.html) and `subscribe phy` to see all physical layer events.

Now, from node A, I try broadcasting frames to see (at various power levels) if node C receives them:

```
> plvl -20
OK
> phy << new TxFrameReq()
AGREE
```

On node C, you'll see receptions, if successful:

```
phy >> RxFrameStartNtf:INFORM[type:CONTROL rxTime:3380134843]
phy >> RxFrameNtf:INFORM[type:CONTROL from:21 rxTime:3380134843]
```

or bad frames if not:

```
phy >> RxFrameStartNtf:INFORM[type:CONTROL rxTime:3389688843]
phy >> BadFrameNtf:INFORM[type:CONTROL rxTime:3389688843]
```

Observations:
- At `plvl -20` dB, almost all frames fail.
- At `plvl -10` dB, almost all frames are successful.
- At `plvl -16` dB, I get a frame loss of about 19%.

The transition between all frames failing to all succeeding is expected to be quite sharp, as is typical in reality for stationary noise, as the FEC performance tends to be quite non-linear. So you'll expect big differences in frame loss rate around the transition region (in this example, at around -16 dB).

Do also note the `plvl 125` dB isn't valid (range of `plvl` is given by `phy.minPowerLevel` to `phy.maxPowerLevel`, -96 dB to 0 dB by default). So setting that would have not worked:

```
> plvl 125
phy[1]: WARNING: Parameter powerLevel set to 0.0
phy[2]: WARNING: Parameter powerLevel set to 0.0
phy[3]: WARNING: Parameter powerLevel set to 0.0
phy: WARNING: Parameter signalPowerLevel set to 0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Also what property should I use instead of "plvl" in scripts?

Comment: `phy[1].powerLevel` for control channel, and `phy[2].powerLevel` for data channel